# Best Way To Receive/Process High Amounts Of Packets/Traffic Via AF_PACKET Socket + EPoll Questions

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I've made a test C program that creates an `AF_PACKET` socket, creates *x* amount of threads via `pthreads`, and within each thread performs `epoll` on the socket's file descriptor. This program was made for Linux and I've compiled it using GCC on Ubuntu 18.04. I've submitted a GitHub Gist of the program [here](https://gist.github.com/gamemann/381bf5dbdc6edc62d158f3d0e49abef5) since it's 200+ lines of code. I am still fairly new to C and network programming. Therefore, I'm sure there are many improvements I can make to the code. I am open to suggestions!

I have two main questions:

1. Is there a better way to receive and process high amounts of packets/traffic in a user space program than the above? I've read using `pthreads` along with `epoll` would be the best option, but I've also looked into `select` and standard `poll`.
2. When the program above is executed without any debug output via `fprintf()`, each thread consumes 100% CPU on the `epoll_wait()` function within the while loop. Is this normal behavior or am I using `epoll` incorrectly? I've looked at some other examples and I use `epoll` the same way as the examples do. I've taken a look at the manual page for `epoll` and I believe I'm using it correctly in my case. I've also tried setting a timeout for the `epoll_wait()` function, but it was still consuming 100% CPU per thread (which I'd expect due to the while loop).

I plan to make a program that will redirect traffic after inspecting the traffic and I expect **a lot** of incoming packets which is why I wanted to see if there is a better way to receive and process high amounts of packets. I also understand I could just use standard `SOCK_DGRAM` or `SOCK_STREAM` sockets and bind them to an IP and port. However, I do want to process and inspect *all* incoming traffic to an interface and forward traffic if necessary (e.g. if the destination address matches a forwarding rule). I also wasn't sure if I should make multiple sockets in this case (perhaps a socket per thread). I did do this initially, but it resulted in unexpected behavior and it was only ever reading from one socket descriptor anyways. Perhaps I wasn't creating the new sockets properly.

Any help is highly appreciated and if you need any more information, please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output well over 50 warning messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: regarding: `int main(uint8_t argc, char *argv[])`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char*argv[] )`  Notice, in the second valid signature, that the first parameter is `int`, not `unsigned char`

Comment: regarding: `uint64_t startingTime = time(NULL);`   The function: `time()` returns a `time_t`, not a `uint64_t`

Comment: The posted code is ignoring the actual return type from several functions, and trying to force the returned value into a `uint8_t`   Which does not work.  Amongst other reasons, often the returned value is < 0

Comment: regarding the definition of `buffer[]`  Strongly suggest the definition be a `struct` that contains instances of the `struct`s that make up the buffer

Comment: regarding: `    uint8_t sockfd;

    sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));

    if (sockfd == -1)`  This code fails to check the returned value `sockfd` because the type: `uint8_t` does not allow values <0.  Suggest using the proper type: `sock_t` (you can also get away with using `int`)

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&pid, NULL, threadHndl, (void *)&stuff);`  the function: `pthread_create()`  can fail, therefore, should always check the returned value.  Any returned value other than 0 indicates an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `pthread_t pid;`   This value, from a call to `pthread_create()` is a `thread id`, not a pid

Comment: regarding; `while(cont) { // Allow the program to stay up until signaled to shutdown. } `This will take up all the CPU cycles. Suggest including some kind of delay, like `sleep(1);`

Comment: regarding: `pid_t threadID = getpid();` this gets the PID_t of the main process, not the thread id. Suggest: `pthread_t threadID = pthread_self();`

Comment: suggest each protocol type from a received message be handle via a `switch()` statement (and perhaps have sub function for each protocol type so as to separate the message processing from the initial input of a message

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for all the helpful information and tips! I wasn't aware the program was generating that many warnings and can't believe I didn't notice the main while loop didn't have a `sleep()` function. That was indeed the reason why the program was consuming so much CPU. I'm also starting to use valid data types. Do you know if my approach to handling a massive amount of incoming packets is recommended (e.g. `epoll()` on one AF_PACKET socket with multiple threads)?

Comment: I would suggest the server code sequence be something like:  --create all the threads and have them block on a condition.    --create a master socket `socket()`  --bind the socket to a specific port `bind()`  tell the program to listen to that port `listen()`  then in a loop: accept a incoming connection `accept()`  --on every successful `accept()`, pass the 'new' socket to an available thread.  Then the input of data will be maximized.   Each thread can determine the protocol and what to do with it.